# How to correctly document wireless network choice for a project?

Tags: rf, wireless, radio, documentation

**Disclaimer**: I have limited wireless knowledge at the moment, I'm currently following the Certified Wireless Network Administrator study guide.

I'm working on an RC car and have the following network requirements:

[image: requirements]

I'm in the planning phase and wish to properly document my wireless network choices and I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm under the impression that I should take a linear approach in determining the wireless standard and the wireless module while not making concrete assumptions about the next stage:

- Network requirements > Wireless standard > Wireless module/controller

I was thinking that an approach of going from requirements to choosing the wireless standard is to first delimit candidates for each function based on the minimum required channel bandwidth to support the required payload rate, using the Nyquist bit rate formula. But the formula refers to a noiseless channel and makes assumptions about modulation and Shannon's capacity requires SNR, which would make assumptions about the wireless module.

I'm not even sure of the proper way to estimate the payload rate because in reality there's a protocol overhead as well and it depends on the chosen wireless standard, that's why I want to use the payload rate and not bit rate.

To recap:

1. What is the correct way to determine candidate wireless standards and wireless modules based on network requirements?
2. How to estimate speed requirements for different functions?

Comment: What do other folk use to meet the requirements? Take a stab in the dark and see if what other folk use is fit for purpose.

Comment: @Andyaka I know what is being used to fulfill the requirements, both the standard and modules but I want to explain the proper process of arriving at those choices.

Comment: Then start with what folk use and justify there choice by working backwards towards what the payload is implied by that choice.